# If your parents give you something As a gift or to make you happy, can they leggally take it from you when u move out?

Tags: united-states

If your parents give you something As a gift or to make you happy, can they leggally take it from you when u move out? Im 17 moving out this weekend but i need to know Because they gave me stuff willinly and i acepted the gifts, So are they aloud to take them back when i move out?

Answer (score 0):

The general rule of law is that a gift can't be taken back, absent circumstances and exceptions that don't apply in this case (e.g. gifts by insolvent people to defraud their debtors, transfers of property made by mistake, gifts made under undue influence by someone with impaired mental capacity).

Whether a parent buying something for the enjoyment of a child in their household is actually a gift that transfers title, or does not divest the parent of ownership since the parent is only letting the child use property that continues to belong to the parent, would be a fact intensive inquiry that a court would have to make if presented with the question.

In general, modern societies aren't very careful about documenting who is the legal owner of most kinds of tangible personal property, which gives rise to the aphorism:

> Possession is nine-tenths of the law.

If you take it with you when you move out, your ownership of it will soon be beyond question for all practical purposes. If your parents try to prevent you from doing so, there are few practical and authoritative ways to resolve the dispute in a cost-effective legally definitive way.

Comment: Can you specify "Whether a parent buying something for the enjoyment of a child in their household is actually a gift that transfers title, or does not divest the parent of ownership since the parent is only letting the child use property that continues to belong to the parent, would be a fact intensive inquiry that a court would have to make if presented with the question." This is confusing to me?

Comment: Mom buys a video game device with her credit card. She lets you use the device. Does that mean she has given you ownership of the device? Or is she just letting you use a device that she still owns? A court could plausibly interpret the legal meaning of what happened either way.

Comment: So is it illelegale for me to take it with me, Or Do i have all right to?

Comment: @ian Dude, you aren't listening. The law is uncertain. There is no black and white answer. A court could interpret it either way. This is very normal in the law. Whether something is legal or not is frequently not 100% clear. Practically, it is unlikely that something bad would happen to you if it happens without a breach of the peace, but we can't give you specific legal advice and a host of factors, only some of them legal, play into that.